# MySQL: what's the difference between a subquery and an alias defined in a `with` statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

E.g. I can do:

```
select *
from posts
where time > (select time from posts where id = 123);
```

Or:

```
with t1 as (
  select time from posts where id = 123
)
select *
from posts
where time > (select time from t1);
```

But not:

```
with t1 as (
  select time from posts where id = 123
)
select *
from posts
where time > t1;
```

So even though `t1` looks like an alias of a subquery, it behaves differently from a subquery. What's the difference? Is it possible to get something like the third query to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table, CTE, or view is only available in the `FROM` clause.  You need to reference it there, so you can access the columns.

So, `t1` needs to be in a `from` clause.  In addition, `t1` is a *set* of rows and columns.  `time` is just one of the columns and your version isn't even referencing that.

You can express this as a `join`:

```
select t1.*
from posts p cross join 
     t1
where p.time > t1.time;
```

Or more commonly as:

```
select t1.*
from posts p join 
     t1
     on p.time > t1.time;
```

Comment: For subqueries, it's also a set of rows and columns. But if it's 1 row and 1 column, MySQL can treat it as a value. It looks like if I add `from posts, t1`, I can do `where posts.time > t1.time`, which is still different from the subquery.

Comment: @LeoJiang . . . If there is one column and no more than one row, then the *subquery* can be treated as a value.  That is called a "scalar subquery", which is your first usage.